# Accessing S3 from inside EKS using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-eks

I have a Python application deployed on EKS (Elastic Kubernetes Service). This application saves large files inside an S3 bucket using the AWS SDK for Python (boto3). Both the EKS cluster and the S3 bucket are in the same region.

My question is, how is communication between the two services (EKS and S3) handled by default?
Do both services communicate directly and internally through the Amazon network, or do they communicate externally via the Internet?

If they communicate via the internet, is there a step by step guide on how to establish a direct internal connection between both services?

Comment: That sounds like a question that technical support of aws should answer to you as customer.

Comment: AWS will not support Basic package.

Comment: In case you don't see the links in the comments below, the relevant ones are: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/iam-roles-for-service-accounts.html and https://aws.github.io/aws-eks-best-practices/security/docs/iam/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`how is communication between the two services (EKS and S3) handled by default?`

By default the network topology of your EKS offers route to the public AWS S3 [endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/s3.html#s3_region).

`Do both services communicate directly and internally through the Amazon network, or do they communicate externally via the Internet?`

Your cluster needs to have network access to the said public AWS S3 endpoints. Example, worker nodes running in public subnet or the use of NAT gateway in private subnet.

`...is there a step by step guide on how to establish a direct internal connection between both services?`

You create VPC endpoints for S3 in the VPC that your EKS runs to ensure network communication with S3 stay within AWS network. VPC endpoints for S3 support both [interface and gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/privatelink-interface-endpoints.html#types-of-vpc-endpoints-for-s3) type. Try this [article](https://tomgregory.com/when-to-use-an-aws-s3-vpc-endpoint/) to learn about the basic of S3 endpoints, you can use the same method to create endpoints in the VPC where your EKS runs. Request to S3 from your pods will then use the endpoint to reach out to S3 within AWS network.

Answer (score 0):

You can add S3 access to your EKS node IAM role, [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-node-role.html) shows you how to add ECR registry access to EKS node IAM role, but it is the same for S3.

The other way is to make environment variables available in your container, see [this link](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html#using-environment-variables), though I would recommend the first way.

Comment: You give the permission to nodes not pods, I'm not sure this can work. I recommend using IRSA: ``https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/iam-roles-for-service-accounts.html`` and he will need s3 vpc endpoint to communicate internally.

Comment: this is what I said, quoting: "You can add S3 access to your EKS node IAM role"

Comment: Did you test it? Create a busybox or awscli pod and get an object from S3.

Comment: I don't do that. You provide permission like that and If it works, all pods can access that S3. Where is security?

Comment: It's your solution and I provided a better one.

Comment: Allowing your pods access to your node's IAM role is a massive security problem. If you take this approach all pods and services on your cluster would have the same IAM permissions. https://aws.github.io/aws-eks-best-practices/security/docs/iam/

Comment: My first answer was to the exact question. My second one is an alternative.

Comment: You were not clear about that at all in your answer. Even re-reading it appears you are recommending to alter the node role to allow the pod to access S3 (which won't even work if you follow the best practices guide). The recommendation for static access keys isn't much better.

Comment: send me the "best practices guide" you follow please.

Comment: Ah, I now know were you come from guys; you run all your deployments in one node pool?

Comment: https://aws.github.io/aws-eks-best-practices/security/docs/iam/ is the official best practices guide published by AWS.